# Any one who can explain the different behavior between run combineGroup and reduceGroup transformation on a grouped dataset?

Tags: apache-flink

Any one who can explain  the different behavior run between  combineGroup and reduceGroup transformation  on a grouped dataset?

```java
ExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataSet<Integer> input = executionEnvironment.fromElements(1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
input.map(new MapFunction<Integer, Tuple1<Integer>>() {
    public Tuple1<Integer> map(Integer value) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple1<Integer>(value
        );
    }
}).groupBy(0).reduceGroup(new GroupReduceFunction<Tuple1<Integer>, Integer>() {
    public void reduce(Iterable<Tuple1<Integer>> values, Collector<Integer> out) throws Exception {
        int sum = 0;

        for (Tuple1<Integer> value : values) {
            sum += value.f0;
        }
        out.collect(sum);
    }
}).print();
```

**This runs reduceGroup transformation on grouped dataset**, and the console show as:

4
6
4
1
7
9
3
5
8

```java
input.map(new MapFunction<Integer, Tuple1<Integer>>() {
    public Tuple1<Integer> map(Integer value) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple1<Integer>(value);
    }
}).groupBy(0).combineGroup(new GroupCombineFunction<Tuple1<Integer>, Integer>() {
    public void combine(Iterable<Tuple1<Integer>> values, Collector<Integer> out) throws Exception {
        int sum = 0;

        for (Tuple1<Integer> value : values) {
            sum += value.f0;
        }
        out.collect(sum);
    }
}).print();
```

**This runs combineGroup on grouped dataset**, and the console show as :

4
8
1
5
9
4
6
3
7

**Obviously, I cant't see any different in this example.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both compute the same thing. Thus, you get the same result for both cases. The differences are somewhat more subtle. Basically, *"The GroupCombine transformation is the generalized form of the combine step in the Combinable GroupReduceFunction"*.

Read the documentation for a detailed explanation and ask again if something is still not clear:

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/dataset_transformations.html#reduce-on-grouped-dataset
- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/dataset_transformations.html#groupreduce-on-grouped-dataset
- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/dataset_transformations.html#groupcombine-on-a-grouped-dataset

Comment: Is there an equivalent operator for DataStream API? If no, how can I implement a combiner for DataStream?